# Jquery limit list elements, hide first-child after

Tags: jquery, onchange, listitem

What I want to achieve is to display ten list items and if next list element is clicked to hide first element, so the list will always be with ten elements

HTML

```
<div id="showMY">
   <ul>
   </ul>​
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $("#dropList").on("change", function () {

        var dropValue = $("#dropList").val();

        $.get("getValues.php", 
        { 
            a: dropValue
        },
        function(data)
        {
            $("#showMY").append(data);


        });

    });
```

And the value that is returned is

```
<li><a href="#">Value</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: TO clarify, when someone clicks on **any** element, the **first** one is hidden and the next element that's hidden is shown?

Comment: Hum... I didn't understand. There are 10 elements, you click on one of them, it hides the first element: there are 9 elements. Where/when do you add a new element?

Comment: _...is to display ten list items and if next list element_ ... thus you are displaying 11 elements?

Comment: I have a dropdown select view, which I forgot to mention and each time a value is clicked it will append to ul and after ten list elements are displayed list goes up with first child removed and clicked element will be displayed below. Hope I'm clear

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WjY2m/

Comment: Or maybe like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WjY2m/1/ You can change it to suit your need by adding `$.get` call

Comment: Thank you for your time Joy, this is what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following code

**HTML:**

```
<select id="drop">
    <option val="item 11"></option>
        <option val="item 12">item 12</option>
        <option val="item 13"> item 13</option>
        <option val="item 14">item 14</option>
        <option val="item 15">item 15</option>
        <option val="item 16">item 16</option>
        <option val="item 17">item 17</option>
        <option val="item 18">item 18</option>
        <option val="item 19">item 19</option>
        <option val="item 20">item 20</option>

</select>

<ul id="container">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
<li>Item 7</li>
<li>Item 8</li>
<li>Item 9</li>
<li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#drop').on('change',function(){
   var dropVal = $(this).val();
   $('ul#container li:visible').first().hide();
    $('ul#container').append("<li> "+ (dropVal) +" "); 
});
```

You can modify it to suit your need by adding your `$.get` call in the code.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WjY2m/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<select id="dropList">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
    <option value="item4">item4</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>

<ul id="showMY">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dropList").change(function() {
        var value = $("#dropList").val();
        $.get("getValues.php", {a: value}, function(data) {
            $("#showMY").append('<li><a href="#">' + data + '</a></li>');
            if($("#showMY li").length > 10) {
                $("#showMY li:first:visible").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#showMY li:first").hide();` this line will try hiding the first element over and over which is already hidden. This should be `$("#showMY li:first:visible").hide();`